# Why are some Python exceptions lower-case?

Tags: python, python-3.x

In Python, exceptions are classes and cased as such. For example: `OSError`.

However, there are some exceptions, such as those in the [socket module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/socket.html#exceptions), that are named in lower-case. For example: `socket.timeout`, `socket.error`.

Why is this?

Comment: I'm not sure this is answerable, but it's very interesting.

Comment: Different authors? No established naming conventions?

Comment: The question may boil down to something similar to "Why are some Python functions `camelCase`?" Some libraries have slightly inconsistent style which has evolved over time. I think PEP-8 speaks to this and was an attempt at "getting everyone on the same page" which was partially successful.

Comment: *Guido has entered the chat*

Comment: Note that ["why" questions on language design are generally considered off-topic here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/170415/144918), as they aren't "practical" -- in the sense of something whose answer would allow you to fix a bug or otherwise change how you go about the practice of programming. (See the "practical, answerable" criteria in the fourth bullet point of https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic, which is ANDed into other conditions).

Comment: I disagree in this specific case, @CharlesDuffy. If I weren't experienced with Python, I might think there was something special about them that means I should handle them a certain way, or that they were subtly different in some other manner that's likely to bite me. I think it's reasonable to ask why they're not like the others.

Comment: @KirkStrauser, "Do exceptions with lower-case names need to be treated differently than others?" is a *practical* question (one that explicitly asks about practical impact, not about rationale), and I wouldn't argue that it would be off-topic (particularly as many such exceptions are implemented by C modules, and thus aren't native Python objects, so there *really are* practical impacts). However, that's distinct from the "why" question asked in the present case.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to the docs,

> exception socket.error A deprecated alias of OSError.
>
> Changed in version 3.3: Following PEP 3151, this class was made an
>   alias of OSError.

#### [PEP 3151 says](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3151/#namespace-pollution)

> while standard exception types live in the root namespace, they are
>   visually distinguished by the fact that they use the CamelCase
>   convention, **while almost all other builtins use lowercase naming**
>   (except True, False, None, Ellipsis and NotImplemented)

Comment: But why not make non-root namespace exceptions CamelCase as well? Making them lower-case doesn't do anything to solve namespace pollution.

Comment: That is the way PSF wants it to be. If you have an objection, raise it in the issues section of [PEP](https://github.com/python/peps/issues)

Comment: @Vishnudev The PSF does not *want* the socket exceptions to be lower case.  They are historical artifacts left as it to not break code.

Comment: It maybe that it was stated in PEP articles after 3151, but the PEP 3151 article suggests the contrary, stating *"while almost all other builtins use lowercase naming"* which means builtins should have lowercase. I'll delete my comment if you think its not appropriate @TerryJanReedy

Comment: @Vishnudev  'other builtins use lowercase naming' (in https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3151/#possible-objections) refers to built-in classes like int, float, complex, tuple, set, list, dict, and some others.  *All* the exceptions in *builtins*, listed at https://docs.python.org/3/library/exceptions.html#built-in-exceptions, are CamelCase.  Additional exceptions defined in other modules should follow that pattern unless there are good reasons otherwise.  Sockets date to when exceptions were strings rather than classes and class instances.  (Deletion would make my responses less sensible.)

Comment: @TerryJanReedy Thanks a lot for the clarifications. Could you edit my answer?